# Unable to Setup correct Virtual Host Configuration on Openlitespeed server

Tags: python, web-deployment, virtualhost, wsgi, openlitespeed

I have recently purchased web hosting, but due to some error on vhost config or wsgi.py file, I am getting 500 error on my domain ([www.trysomething.in](http://www.trysomething.in)) and using openlitespeed server

```
This is my context part of vhost Config
```

```
    context / {
    
      type                    appserver
    
      URI                      /
    
      location              /home/trysomething.in/public_html/Cking_coupons/
    
      binPath              /usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lswsgi
    
      appType            wsgi
    
      startupFile        Cking_coupons/wsgi.py 
    
      envType            1
    
      env                     LS_PYTHONBIN=/home/trysomething.in/public_html/bin/pyhton
    
      env                     PYTHONHOME=/home/trysomething.in/public_html/
    
    }
```

```
This is my wsgi.py file
```

```
    """
    WSGI config for Cking_coupons project.
    It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.
    For more information on this file, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/
    """
    
    import os
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Cking_coupons.settings')
    application = get_wsgi_application()
```

```
Also, I tried to access it through <my_IP:Port_no> using python manage.py runserver command, and it worked fine, but I am getting 500 error in domain, also I followed this blog https://cyberpanel.net/blog/2019/01/10/how-to-setup-django-application-on-cyberpanel-openlitespeed/

My Code is alright and everything is fine, the problem is somewhere in vhost config or virtual env or wsgi file.

Please help
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
startupFile        wsgi.py
```

It is relative to the `location` path.

Comment: How to try that?

Comment: just update the config you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by correcting the Environment values as described here:
https://openlitespeed.org/kb/python-wsgi-applications/

I also read that some people had to reinstall django.